# Definite double integral of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am in trouble in the calculation of the following double integral:
$$\int_0^a d\rho\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\exp(-ik\rho(\sin(\theta_0)\cos(\phi_0-\phi)+\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\phi_1-\phi)))\rho$$
Many thanks

Comment: Would you care to tell us what sort of problem gave rise to this integral?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I know such integrals from experience; they usually have to do with a FT of a function of finite support over a disk.  These arise in, for example, diffraction of a plane wave by a transparent disk in an otherwise opaque plane (in this case, the plane wave being oblique to the disk).

Comment: @Harald Hanche Olsen: rigordonna is right. It's an integral related to a Fraunhofer diffraction problem.

Comment: Right. I *knew* there was something familiar there, but had forgotten. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the angular integral, you may rewrite the angular terms in the form

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi \exp{(-i k \rho A \cos{(\phi - \phi')})} $$

where $A$ and $\phi'$ may be expressed in terms of the other angles listed in the original integral.  This integral is simply a Bessel function:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi \: \exp{(-i k \rho A \cos{(\phi - \phi')})} = 2 \pi J_0{( k \rho A)}$$

The radial integral is then

$$2 \pi \int_0^a d \rho \: \rho J_0{( k \rho A)} = 2 \pi a^2 \frac{J_1{(k A a)}}{k A a}$$

**EDIT**

To be explicit, one may find $A$ by determining the coefficients of $\cos{\phi}$ and $\sin{\phi}$; let's say the coefficients are $C$ and $S$, respectively.  Then define $\phi' = \arctan{\frac{S}{C}}$ such that

$$C \cos{\phi} + S \sin{\phi} = \sqrt{C^2+S^2} \cos(\phi - \phi')$$

In manipulating the expression in the original integral, one finds that

$$C = \sin{\theta_0} \cos{\phi_0} + \sin{\theta_1} \cos {\phi_1}$$
$$S = \sin{\theta_0} \sin{\phi_0} + \sin{\theta_1} \sin{\phi_1}$$